# How best to instantiate a 2nd Vue instance for Non parent-child communication

Tags: vue.js

I'm working through a tutorial to learn Vue 2.0 and just finished a lesson on communication using an event bus to allow for communication with components other than the immediate parent.

The code presented in the tutorial gave me an error however and I was able to solve it on my own as I'll explain below. I'd like to understand "why" the original code didn't work though just for my own learning and understanding.

The code given in the tutorial is as follows:

```
Window.Event = new Vue();

Vue.component('coupon', {

    template: '<input placeholder="Coupon Code" @blur="onCouponApplied">',

    methods: {
        onCouponApplied() {
            Event.$emit('applied');
        }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',

    created() {
        Event.$on('applied', () => alert('Handling it!'));
    }
});
```

When I tried to run, I received an error: "TypeError: Event.$on is not a function". After researching online, I simply changed the instantiation of the first Vue instance to:

```
var bus = new Vue();
```

and then referred to the emit / on as follows:

```
bus.$emit('applied');
```

and

```
bus.$on('applied', () => alert('Handling it!'));
```

For my own understanding, I'd appreciate some help with the following:

1. Why would the original Window.Event format not have worked for me
   when it appears to have worked for others?
2. There were some comments in the comments section of this tutorial
   along the lines of using Window.Event as not being a best practice,
   but they didn't explain why.
3. Is there anything wrong with the way that I've done it, and is there
   any functionality I'd be losing by not using the original
   Window.Event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the tutorial is literally recommending this exact line,

```
window.Event = new Vue()
```

then they are recommending *a bad idea*. `Event` is a [native browser object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event), if even if you could override it, you definitely should not. You would be replacing an object that many other libraries, including likely Vue itself, rely on.

If, on the other hand, you actually wrote this code

```
Window.Event = new Vue()
```

then you added your Vue object to whatever `Window` is in your browser. Note the capital `W`. `Window` is not the same as `window`. Lowercase `window` refers to the global object in all browsers. In chrome, `Window` refers to something else (not sure exactly what).

So, when you try to call `Event.$on()`, you are referencing the native Event object I linked above, and not the bus you attempted to create, which results in your error.

Comment: Wow, yes the capital 'W' was my problem! Embarrassing but thanks so much. So if I read you correctly, the way I've done it using var bus is a better approach in any case?

Comment: @DustinS `var bus` is perfectly fine!

Comment: @DustinS I should note, there are times you may want to write `window.bus`. If, for example, you were using webpack to compile multiple separate files you may need to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind... I see later on in the series there is a section on Webpack as well.